# Coverting an unknown length string to lower case issues

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file-io

So I'm not very good with C but I'm designing a GLUT application that reads in a file that is not case sensitive. To make it easier I want to convert my strings to all lower case. I made a function makeLower that is modifying a variable that was passed in by reference.

I have a While Loop in the method makeLower that seems to get through part of the first iteration of the while loop and then the EXE crashes. Any tips would be great, thanks!

Output:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project 1\Debug>"Project 1.e
xe" ez.txt

Line is #draw a diamond ring

Character is #
```

Then error "project 1.exe has stopped working"

Code:

```
void makeLower(char *input[]){
    int i = 0;
    printf("Line is %s\n", *input);

    while(input[i] != "\0"){
        printf("Character is %c\n", *input[i]); 
        if(*input[i] >= 'A' && *input[i] <= 'Z'){
            *input[i] = tolower(*input[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char linebyline [50], *lineStr = linebyline;
    char test;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    while(!feof(file) && file != NULL){
        fgets(lineStr , 100, file);
        makeLower(&lineStr);
        printf("%s",lineStr);

        //directFile();

    }
    fclose(file);


    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger? Besides that I can give you a hint: Do you know what the pointer indirection operator (`*`) does, for example in the expression `*input[i]`? I suggest you look over all those. :)

Comment: Doesn't it deference the variable? Since it was passed into the function by reference? I'm not very good with C tbh.

Comment: If you have a string (pointer to a `char`) you can get a single character by using `string[i]` where `i` is a number between 0 and the length of the string minus one, or `*(string + i)`. The latter is actually what the compiler translates `string[i]` to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see more problems now, so I extend my comments to an answer:

You allocate an array of 50 characters, but tell `fgets` to get up to 100 characters, which might be fatal as `fgets` will overwrite memory not in the string.

When passing a C string to a function, you don't have to pass the address of the pointer to the string (`&lineStr`), the actual pointer or array is okay. This means you can change the `makeLower` function to `void makeLower(char *input)` or `void makeLower(char input[])`. Right now the argument to `makeLower` is declared as an array or char pointers, not a pointer to an array of char.

In the new `makeLower` I proposed above, you can access single characters either as an array (`input[i]`) or as a pointer plus offset (`*(input + i)`. Like I said in my comment, the last version is what the compiler will probably create if you use the first. But the first is more readable so I suggest that.

Also in `makeLower` you make a comparison with `"\0"`, which is a string and not a character. This is almost right actually: You should use `input[i] != '\0'`.

And finally this is how I would implement it:

```
void makeLower(char *input)
{
    while (*input != '\0')  /* "while (*input)" would also work */
    {
        *input = tolower(*input);
        input++;
    }
}
```

A few explanations about the function:

- All char arrays can be converted to a char pointer, but not the other way around. Passing char pointer is the most common way to pass a string actually, as you can see from all standard functions that accepts strings (like `strlen` or `strcpy`.)
- The expression `*input` *dereferences* (i.e. takes the value of what a pointer points to) the string. It is the same as `*(input + 0)` and so get the value of the first character in the string.
- While the first character in the string is not `'\0'` (which technically is a normal zero) we will loop.
- Get the first character of the string and pass it to the `tolower` function. This will work no matter what the character is, `tolower` will only turn upper case characters to lower case, all other characters will be returned as they already were.
- The result of `tolower` copied over the first character. This works because the right hand side of an assignment must be executed before the assignment, so there will not be any error or problem.
- Last we increase the pointer by one. This will make `input` point to the next character in the string. This works because `input` is a local variable, so operations on the *pointer* will not affect anything in the calling function.

This function can now be called like this:

```
char input[100];
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
printf("before: \"%s\"\n", input);
makeLower(input);
printf("after : \"%s\"\n", input);
```

Comment: Im pretty terrible at C when it comes to references and such. Your post solved my problem and was super enlightening! With that explanation i don't think ill be having any issues with pass by reference. Especially with strings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try while(*input[i] != "\0") instead of what you have ? For some reason you seem to pass to your function a pointer to pointer to char (*input[]) and &lineStr so it would make sense to dereference twice when you check for string terminator character "\0"....

Just a thought, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't know that the string is going to equal '\0' when you want it to. So you may be going out of bounds which is very likely that you don't know the length of the string.

Comment: The thing it the first iteration is not even finishing. Character is #
is only the first character of the line. The next output should say 'Character is d'

Comment: Then I think Joachim is probably right because I know in c++ using the array operator notation automatically dereferences a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand things, it's fine to pass '\0' to `tolower()`. It's a valid `unsigned char` value, and `tolower()` simply returns the input character if it is not able to do any conversion.

Thus, the loop can be succinctly put as:

```
while(input[i] = tolower(input[i]))
  ++i;
```

This does one more call to `tolower()`, but it's shorter and (imo) quite clear. Just wanted to mention it as an alternative.